# больница vs госпиталь

Tags: выбор-слова, синонимы

Меня учили, что это синонимы. Но по прочтении некоторых книг мне кажется, что все-таки некоторая смысловая разница есть. А какая?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Словари определяют госпиталь преимущественно как военное лечебное учреждение:

> ГОСПИТАЛЬ, -я; м. [нем. Hospital]
>   Лечебное учреждение, больница (преимущественно военная).
>
> [Большой толковый словарь](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%E3%EE%F1%EF%E8%F2%E0%EB%FC&all=x)

[Википедия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C) приводит целую классификацию госпиталей:

> Го́спиталь (от лат. hospitalis, гостеприимный) — медицинское учреждение вооружённых сил многих государств, предназначенное для оказания медицинской помощи военнослужащим.
>   На территории России различают госпитали:
>
> - постоянные (работающие в мирное время): гарнизонные, окружные, видов вооружённых сил, центральные;
> - формируемые в военное время: полевые передвижные госпитали, эвакуационные госпитали, тыловые госпитали.

В то же время госпитали есть не только у военных, но и других "силовых" структур: МВД (полиция), МЧС (служба спасения, пожарная служба) и т. п.

Судя по всему и железнодорожники тоже называют свои больницы госпиталями (у них, кстати есть своя собственная пожарная служба):

> Центральный клинический госпиталь с научно-клиническим центром физиологии (Железнодорожная больница)

Можно вспомнить, что слово "госпиталь" связано с историей крестовых походов и монашескими орденами (например существовал [Орден госпитальеров](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B)). Наверное поэтому можно встретить слово "госпиталь" в названиях больниц, организационно связанных с религией:

> Больница городская клиническая № 70 (Госпиталь мира и милосердия Спасо-Перовский).

Вообще говоря английское слово hospital относится к так называемым "ложным друзьям переводчика" - встретив это слово неопытный переводчик сразу же переводит его как "госпиталь", в то время как основным значением в русском языке для этого слова является "больница". Поэтому сегодня многие названия иностранных лечебных учреждений часто необоснованно переводят как "госпиталь".